# Depth First Search using Map Reduce

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce, graph-algorithm

I have successfully implemented the Shortest Path algorithm in Hadoop Map Reduce(Breath First Search). However I have a question that:
Is it possible to do graph traversal "**Depth First Search**" using **Hadoop map reduce** ?
Any Links..?

Answer (score 2):

The nature of the Depth First Search makes it inappropriate for map reduce jobs. Because you only follow one strict path to the end before forking into another one. That lead to the fact that you can't use the scalability provided by hadoop properly. I'm not aware of a fine working implementation and I'm pretty sure you won't find one which uses the MapReduce paradigm in a good way.

If you try to implement graph algorithms in hadoop on your own you might want to have a look at some useful frameworks like [Apache Giraph](https://giraph.apache.org/), [xrime](http://xrime.sourceforge.net/) or [Pegasus](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pegasus/what%20is%20pegasus.htm). xrime also contains a shortest path implementation which might be interesting for you.